# sql query displaying correct values but wrong 'id'

Tags: mysql, sql, algorithm, debugging, syntax

I have an sql query like the following

```html
select *
from register_bs
INNER JOIN spouse_details ON register_bs.reg = spouse_details.reg
WHERE country NOT IN('Australia', 'USA', 'Germany', 'Canada');
```

This query is displaying correct values for all fields except the 'id' field, it's giving some random id for every data. for example the below data:
[image]

when i click on any button of the above data it is going to edit page with different data like below

[image]

because the id got is wrong

As there are 900 columns in my register_bs table, I cant use field alias instead of `*`. Can anyone please tell me how to correct my statement to get the correct id? Thanks in advance

Comment: Show us your database model, and some sample of data.

Comment: I would dispute that the id is random -that's not possible with the code published - what makes you think it is?, do you have examples?

Comment: Make it easy (and possible) to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: Wnat about `SELECT register_bs.*` and enumerate each of the columns in `spouse_details` (other than `id`)?

Comment: @Rumpelstinsk i have updated

Comment: @P.Salmon i have updated question

Comment: @Nick am not that good in sql, if you dont mind can you please edit my code and show me asn answer

Comment: @SeepSooo what are the fields in `spouse_details`?

Comment: @SeepSooo what is your application framework? how are you running the query?

Comment: I cannot replicate the assertion at the heart of this question

Comment: @Nick there are 19 columns in spouse details, but both the tables id is not same. am using plain php

Comment: Your published query brings back every record where country is not in a list..perhaps it should be amended to only bring back 1 record for the person of interest. I cannot see where the published query comes into the process.

Comment: But in both tables `id` has the same column name? so your problem is that the `id` value from `spouse_details` is overwriting the `id` from `register_bs`. Are there any other columns which in the two tables which have the same name (other than `id` and `reg`)?

Comment: @Nick no reg is the same in both tables, id is different in both. and there are no other same fields

Comment: @Nick i have tried Vignesh Kumar's answer and its working very fine

Comment: @SeepSooo I'm glad to hear it. It's a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

First execute the below query in server and check the values of `ID`

```
SELECT register_bs.ID AS ValidateedID, register_bs.*, spouse_details.* 
FROM register_bs INNER JOIN spouse_details ON register_bs.reg = spouse_details.reg
WHERE country NOT IN('Australia', 'USA', 'Germany', 'Canada');
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check if the two tables that you have joined have the same column name for their id.
If yes, specify the table first and then the column of the id you want to retrieve. 
e.g. `register_bs.id`

Comment: i didnt understand , can you please edit my code and show an exampl

Comment: id of both tables are different